# With List of Figures at start of extbook — it's title is in the header

Tags: sectioning

I'm using the `extbook` document class to put together a book of and about music. Rendering with XeLaTeX

For some reason the header is listing the title of the `List of Figures` in the headers of each page following the display of the `List of Figures`.

At first I thought this was occurring because I wasn't including Chapters in the book, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,11pt]{extbook}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[outer=2.2cm,inner=2.2cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm,heightrounded,marginparwidth=1.2cm, marginparsep=.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figures Listed}

\frontmatter

\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\section{First Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[1-30]

\begin{figure}[ht]
Some Figure Item
\label{fig:A Figure}
\caption[A Figure]{}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Subsection Two}

\lipsum[1-30]

\begin{figure}[ht]
Some Figure Item
\label{fig:Another Figure}
\caption[Another Figure]{}
\end{figure}

\section{Second Section}

\subsection{Subsection Three}

\lipsum[1-30]

\subsection{Subsection Fore}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

And the undesired result:

[image: The undesired result]

I expect I'm doing something wrong, but not sure what. Any ideas?

---

UPDATE

Am able to work around the problem based on [this tip](https://texblog.org/2014/03/25/table-of-contents-list-of-figures-and-tables-as-sections-in-a-report/) with following code:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \subsection{\contentsname}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
}

\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \subsection{\contentsname}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
}
\makeatother
```

Which if I'm understanding correctly is decreasing the `sectional` *value* of the table header from `Chapter` to `Subsection`.

---

### Solution

Revisited original decision to use Section and Subsections without Chapters, I realized that the reason to avoid Chapters had been because of the blank page inserted, which I have suppressed with `titlesec` package as follows:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Large\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
% don't add page breaks before chapters.
    \titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
```

Comment: For me, adding a `\chapter` and running LaTeX twice solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you need to insert a `\chapter`.  This worked for me:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,11pt]{extbook}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[outer=2.2cm,inner=2.2cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm,heightrounded,marginparwidth=1.2cm, marginparsep=.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figures Listed}

\frontmatter

\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[1-30]

\begin{figure}[ht]
Some Figure Item
\label{fig:A Figure}
\caption[A Figure]{}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Subsection Two}

\lipsum[1-30]

\begin{figure}[ht]
Some Figure Item
\label{fig:Another Figure}
\caption[Another Figure]{}
\end{figure}

\section{Second Section}

\subsection{Subsection Three}

\lipsum[1-30]

\subsection{Subsection Fore}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

And the results:

[image: Left page]
[image: Right page]

Comment: Mmmm, but I don't want a chapter if it can be avoided. The document doesn't really _have_ chapters.

Comment: I've never used extbook.  There is extarticle, maybe it is a pendant to article.  In that case, you won't have chapters and `\section` is the highest sectioning-command available.  But on the other hand, than you cannot use `\frontmatter` and its relatives.  Nevertheless, I'd say, you should either use `\chapter` in extbook-class and be happy with `\frontmatter`.  Or switch to extarticle-class in order to avoid using `\chapter`.  Staying with extbook but not using `\chapter` will undoubtedly lead to that erroneous results of your question.

Comment: Thanks to your post, I revisited my original decision to not use chapters and remembered that the problem was that I didn't want blank pages between paragraphs, which was solved with code added in the addition to the question.